# Nested routes with react-router v5 doesn't update layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to split my app in 2 different parts.

An exam list should link to a student list.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useRouteMatch
} from 'react-router-dom';

// doesn't work
const ExamList = () => {
  return (
    <p>
      current: ExamList, <Link to='/students'>to Students</Link>
    </p>
  );
};

// nested router
const Exams = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <ExamList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

// worked 
const Students = () => {
  return (
    <p>
      current: Students, <Link to='/'>to Exams</Link>
    </p>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <Exams />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/students'>
        <Students />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`"/"` click the link (to Students) doesn't render `Students` component, but if I refresh the browser, the `Students` component will be rendered currectly.

`"/students"` click the link (to Exams) worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not just nesting routes, but you're also nesting routers.

So change `Exams` from this:

```
const Exams = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <ExamList />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

to  this:

```
const Exams = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={path}>
        <ExamList />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

---

I recommend you take a look at this [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) for a good idea of where to go from here / how to approach nested routes in general.